# IF statement not working in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function, formatting

So I'm using Google Sheets and I'm trying to determine whether or not cells in a certain column `AO` have a higher value then cells in another column `O`. My formula is `=IF(AO6 > O6,"UNDER","OVER")`. The value in `AO6` is `217` and the value in `O6` is `225`. However, the cell keeps saying `UNDER` when it should be saying `OVER`. 217 is not greater than 225??? Am I missing something???

Comment: Please share a link to your sheet, being sure to set permissions to "Anyone with the link can Edit" (or at least "...can View"). There is little anyone can tell you without being able to see the data and context.

Answer (score 2):

**This is caused by formatting... Most likely cell AO is formatted (or evaluated) as `Plain text` and text value is always zero. You can fix it by using `VALUE()` or by changing formatting for those involved cells**

```
=IF(VALUE(AO6) > VALUE(O6), "UNDER", "OVER")
```

[image]

---

[image]